# Electric field direction at line of intersection of 3 mirror planes

Tags: electrostatics, charge, symmetry

[image: Page 7 and 8]

The link to the paper is [Electric Field inside a non-conducting cubic surface](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.07703v1.pdf)

On page $7$ and $8$ of the paper.

My doubt is:

Any plane passing through two planes $\pi_{1}$ and $\pi_{2}$ can be represented in the form $\pi_{1} + \lambda \pi_{2}$. The 3 planes need not be mutually planar. According to me, the direction of electric field at point P on the intersection of the 3 non planar planes, can there never be a common direction of the line of intersection as the paper says?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this is just a poor choice of words on the authors' part.  They speak of

> ... three mutually non-parallel mirror planes that intersect at some point $P$...

On its face, this phrase isn't terribly clear.  (Talking about the intersection of *parallel* planes is something of a vacuous notion, after all.)  But from the subsequent discussion, it is clear that they really mean something like

> ... three mirror planes that only mutually intersect at a single point $P$...

which is in fact true for the case they discuss immediately following (the $x = 0$, $y = 0$, and $z = 0$ planes for the cube.)

You are correct, though, that the intersection of three distinct mirror planes for a charge distribution could be more than a single point.  A simple example would be four equal charges at the points $(\pm a, 0,0)$ and $(0,\pm a, 0)$.  The planes $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $x + y = 0$, and $x - y = 0$ are all mirror planes.  But the intersection of these planes is the entire $z$-axis;  and for points other than $z = 0$, the electric field does not vanish at points in this intersection.